# how to show the map $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1+x_2, x_1-x_2)$ is a surjective isometry for specified metrics on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

> **Question:** Show that the map $f:(\Bbb R^2, d^1)\to(\Bbb R^2, d^\infty)$ defined by $$f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1+x_2, x_1-x_2)$$ is a surjective isometry.

$d^1(x,y)$ is the taxi-cab metric:

$$d^1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^2|x_i-y_i|\;;$$

$d^\infty(x,y)$ is the Euclidean metric:

$$d^\infty(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2(x_i-y_i)^2}\;.$$

I failed to find some examples from notes and internet, so I don't know how to start this problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: start with the definition of isometry

Comment: Is that really $d^{\infty}$? It looks like the definition of $d^2$...

Comment: Sorry, d^infinity(x,y)= max{|xi-yi|}

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake, Thomas.

Comment: I think I need to show:d^infinity(x,y)=d^1(x,y), or max{|x1-y1|,|x2-y2|}=|x1-y1|+|x2-y2|} by definition of isometry.  f(x,y)=(x+y,x-y),  then I got stuck.

Comment: Here is a link to the exact same question that I posted and then answered myself. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131245/show-f-is-a-surjective-isometry/1131401#1131401

Answer (score 0):

So I have been able to find a solution. You ought to correct the definition of $d^{\infty}$ though.

I must show that $$d^{1}(x,y) = d^{\infty}(f(x),f(y)).$$ I have that $$f(x) = f(x_1,x_2)= (x_1+x_2,x_1-x_2)$$ On the L.H.S. of the first equation we have $$d^{1}(x,y)= |(x_1-y_1)|+|(x_2-y_2)|$$ which is the Taxi Cab metric on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ On the R.H.S. we have $$ d^{\infty}(f(x),f(y)) =  d^{\infty}(f(x_1,x_1),f(y_1,y_2))= d^{\infty}((x_1+x_2,x_1-x_2),(y_1+y_2,y_1-y_2))$$ So that we get $$max:\{|(x_1+x_2)-(y_1+y_2)|,|(x_1-x_2)-(y_1-y_2)|\}$$ 
and this is $$max:\{|(x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2)|,|(x_1-y_1)-(x_2-y_2)|\}$$ and it is clear that  $$d^{1}(x,y) = d^{\infty}(f(x),f(y)).$$ The rest is shown above by showing that $f$ is invertible.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857246/showing-an-isometry/2857254#2857254.